Splunk REST API - How to add a webhook action to an existing reports
I can't seem the Splunk REST API to add a webhook action to an existing report. I looked into Splunk REST API - How to add a webhook action? and tried it, the sample will create new alert only (but not report) and error if there is existing name.
Can anyone please help to provide a sample how to update an existing report like adding a webhook?
Thanks
